# Why is restarting tomcat9 resolving networking issues?

Tags: ubuntu, networking, tomcat

I'm facing a very strange issue. Since a few days, several times per day, my ubuntu server is not able to establish outbound connections. I'm able to log in using SSH, connect to the web application hosted by the apache webserver but trying to install packages using apt or doing a telnet google.com 443 results in errors like "telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused" or "connect (111: Connection refused) Cannot initiate the connection to fr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (2001:860:f70a::2). - connect (101: Network is unreachable)".

At first, I was suspecting iptables rules but removing them all does not solve the issue. On the other hand, if I stop the tomcat9 application server, everything starts working again.

I cannot imagine how tomcat can influence the network connectivity of my server. The exact same applications are deployed on other, similar, Ubuntu 18.04 servers that are not affected by this issue.

Any tips on what to check to identify the underlying issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much!

Edit>

```
#ping google.com
PING google.com (172.217.170.14) 56(84) bytes of data.
From _gateway (192.168.10.254) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
64 bytes from jnb02s02-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.170.14): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=226 ms
64 bytes from jnb02s02-in-f14.1e100.net (172.217.170.14): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=226 ms



# traceroute google.com
traceroute to google.com (172.217.170.14), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  _gateway (192.168.10.254)  0.889 ms !H  0.446 ms !H  0.406 ms !H


# ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 192.168.10.254 dev eth0 src 192.168.10.142 uid 0 
cache
```

Comment: Have you tried ping? Does it work?

Comment: Can you add more information like: What does IPv4 do? What does your gateway look like at the moment it's not working? (`ip route get 8.8.8.8`). You could also try creating a packet dump with tcpdump.

Comment: @Marco I've edited my question with two new pieces of information. Thanks!

Comment: What kind of device is in the middle? Could it be a wrongly configured firewall/nat device? Do these connection to google work from that gateway when it’s happening? There are a lot of reasons for this to happen. I’m particulary interested in the connection refused.

Comment: I second Marco. The ICMP message "Destination Host unreachable" above has been created by your firewall device 192.168.10.254, and definitely could be the reason for the connection refused.

Comment: Could you make a network capture with `sudo tcpdump -w network_capture.pcap -npi any "(host $dst_IP and port $dst_port) or icmp"`. Check in the ICMP payload for the headers of the packet that generated the ICMP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, the people who provided the infrastructure did put some sort of outbound connection rate limiter that was triggered by incessant reverse DNS requests by a DCM4CHEE docker container.

I was assured repeatedly that no such mechanism was actiavted in their firewall and I had not thought about checking outbound DNS connections so I did not notice the "huge" rate at which they were performed.

I've lost 40+ hours investigating this issue and was able to solve it in 5 minutes once they came clean about it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

One possible source for the problem could be number of open file descriptors exceeding system limit.

When the system is in that state, run `cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr`. The output looks like this:

```
46512   0   9223372036854775807
```

If the first number is close to third number, it means that all available file descriptors are in use.

To increase number of available file descriptors, you can run

```
sysctl -w fs.file-max=<number>
sysctl -p
```

Where `<number>` is higher than your existing maximum limit (third column in previous output).

Comment: I will test that as soon as the system find itself in the same state. I was actually thinking about sockets that could perhaps not be opened which would explain why ingoing connections were still possible (since typically, AFAIK apache keeps a number of listening sockets open and does not open them on demand). It looks like it may be linked to your suggestion. Thanks a lot! I'll validate the answer as soon as I have tested it :-)

Comment: So, I'm afraid that's not it. sockstat does not return anything out of the ordinary either. I have absolutely no clue what's happening.